# Mails Going to spam even after adding SPF and DKIM

Tags: spam, webmail

I've configured Webmail in Cpanel, and enabled SPF and DKIM, but still the mails are going to spam in gmail. Yahoo is receiving the mails in inbox. My Domain and IP are not blacklisted. Please let me know if anyone knows the solution.

Comment: Gmail has very strict restriction. I also host my site with hosting provider and when I use mail to send to gmail address, it will go to SPAM folder. My hosting provider recommend me to ask the recipient to mark my mail as whitelist.

Comment: Please note: If've made recent changes in your DKIM and SPF you MUST wait 3 or 4 days for Gmail to actually be aware of them. After implementing DKIM I had to way some days for it start working on Gmail, seems like they do some kind of cache.

Comment: @TCB13 Do you have any links to where this is documented?

Comment: @crmpicco no. I'm not even sure that kind of caching happens, but I've noticed this behavior in the hundreds of deployments I managed along the years.

Answer (score 1):

Nerdy Bird here! Have you by any chance tailed any of the exim error logs?

Try this:
Assuming you have root access to the server, ssh into the server as Root, the run the line below (NOTE: username is the beginning of the email address 'john@somedomain.com'. So in the below example, you would replace username with john). This makes searching the logs much easier).

```
tail -f /var/log/exim_mainlog | grep -i username
```

Upon running the above line, send an email from your webmail account to another account (Gmail in this case). Once you've done that, output should display in the terminal. The output is the best insight into your mail issue.

Also, if you have command line access, try using telnet. If you can connect by running the following line, you can rule out issues with outgoing ports on the server.

FOR PORT 25:

```
telnet alt2.gmail-smtp.in.l.google.com 25
```

If you get a connected message, port 25 is open and able to send mail.

FOR PORT 26:

```
telnet alt2.gmail-smtp.in.l.google.com 26
```

If you get a connected message, port 26 is open and able to send mail.

**Other Possible Issues**

1. You could possible not have a RDNS (reverse dns record) setup for your server's/domain's IP address. If not, please consult with your Hosting provider to see that gets added and allow time for propagation.
2. Port mail is being sent on is by default port 25. Sometimes ISPs' block mail coming from port 25. Try changing this port to port 26. This is typically done via command line or in WHM (Webhost Manager). If you do not have access to WHM or CMD, contact your hosting provider.

   1. Although you stated your IP is not blacklisted, please check again. We use MXtoolbox.com

Hope this helps. Need more let us know.

Nerdy Bird

Comment: Thanks NerdyBird. I don't have access to SSH as I'm using shared hosting. I'll try contacting my hosting provider.

Comment: When you contact them, send them a link to this string so they can see my answer. I used to work for two of the best webhosting companies in the US, so I think I know what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried a whole lot of things but at the end, I verified my site in https://www.google.com/webmasters and added it as a property after which email from my webmail started going to Gmail inbox again instead of spam.